# Integrate $\iint_D 16\cos((4x+2y)^2)dxdy$ with help of contour lines.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$\iint_D 16\cos((4x+2y)^2)dxdy, \\D: 12\leq4x+2y\leq24\\x\geq0\\y\geq0$$

So one method I've learned to deal with this kind of problem is by integration along the contour lines. So if I substitute as $t=4x+2y$ and define my area function as $A(t)=\frac{t^2}{2}$.

From here I'm trying to use: $$\iint_D f(g(x,y))dxdy=\int_a^bf(t) \ A'(t) dt$$

In my case this yields: $$\iint_D 16\cos((4x+2y)^2)dxdy=\int_{12}^{24}16\cos(t^2)\ t\ dt=8(\sin(24^2)-\sin(12^2))$$

I am not quite sure where my mistake is.

Comment: If you are trying to use Green's Theorem, you need to integrate all the way around the contour, made of four line segments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen this method for evaluating a double integral before, but I think I get the idea. Pretty cool stuff! Here's my take on the problem.

For $a,b\in[12,24]$ with $a<b$ define a set $\Omega(a,b)$ by $$\Omega(a,b)=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{Q}_1\big|a<4x+2y<b\}$$ The area of $\Omega(a,b)$ is easily seen to be $\frac{b^2-a^2}{16}$. Next, fix $t\in [12,24)$ and let $\Delta t$ be a very small positive number. Note the area of $\Omega(t,t+\Delta t)$ is approximately $\frac{t\Delta t}{8}$. Now since $f(x,y)\approx 16\cos(t^2)$ for any $(x,y)\in \Omega(t,t+\Delta t)$ we see that the volume between of the region of space beneath (or above) $z=f(x,y)$ over our set $\Omega(t,t+ \Delta t)$ is approximately $$16\cos(t^2) \cdot \frac{t \Delta t}{8}=2t\cos(t^2)\Delta t$$ Therefore, $$\iint_{D}f(x,y)dA=\int_{12}^{24}2t\cos(t^2)dt=\sin(25^2)-\sin(12^2)$$ After reading your post I see your issue is your area function, $A(t)$.